# Collect static error while deploying app on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I had a problem with a Django app uploaded on Heroku, so I deleted the app and I'm trying to re-upload it. But now an error occurs while collectstatic is running.

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ExG5.png)

This what I have in settings.py for the statics files:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
if os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG') == 'PRODUCTION':

        # Static files settings
        PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

        STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')

        # Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
        STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'))

        STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

        db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
        DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

I don't understand why it's occurring as the only things I changed compared to the previous version is the name of the project. Also, I'm on Window, so it's normal that I don't have Linux files. How can I fix this error ? Or how can I install the file ? (I tested with git bash, but the commands are not recognized).